# How to Define and use Different User Types in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The application has the following users and controller in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

**AppUser**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DifferentUser**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class DifferentUser : AppUser
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DifferentUserController.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    namespace MyApp.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "DifferentUser")]
        public class DifferentUserController : Controller
        {

            private UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

            public DifferentUserController(UserManager<AppUser> _userManager)
            {
                userManager = _userManager;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                var user = (DifferentUser) await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                return View("~/Views/DifferentUser/Index.cshtml", user);
            }
        }
    }
```

Within the DifferentUserController, the Index method should return the view, and pass it the currently logged in DifferentUser. But it returns the following error.

`InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MyApp.Models.AppUser' to type 'MyApp.Models.DifferentUser'.`

What is the correct/best way of handling different user types in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyApp.Models;
using MyApp.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) =>
            Configuration = configuration;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>,
                CustomPasswordValidator>();

            services.AddTransient<IUserValidator<AppUser>,
                CustomUserValidator>();

            services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
                opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UserManager<AppUser>` expects an `AppUser` but wont be able to cast because it is unaware of `DifferentUser` in this context. If you use `UserManager<DifferentUser>` it should be able to provide the desired behavior.

Comment: The trick here would be to make sure the necessary generics are registered with the IoC container so that the correct type is injected into the controller.

Comment: Tried that: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[MyApp.Models.DifferentUser]' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Controllers.DifferentUserController'.

Comment: did you register the appropriate manager with the container?

Comment: I used UserManager<DifferentUser>. Is that correct?

Comment: you would have setup identity at startup for only AppUser, so the container is only aware of that type of user manager. I asked if you also included DifferentUser when setting up identity. when you setup identity users it registers their usermanager with the container so that it can be resolved when injecting managers. If not it wont know how to resolve them

Comment: I added Startup.cs at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Review the following source code which shows what I explained in my previous comment https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/8ef14785a4a1e416189ca1137eb13f43c2f4349d/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38

Comment: Very sorry, but this did not help me understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the need to cast, you could use an enum to define your user type and use your AppUser class in both cases. This will make it possible in this scenario.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public UserType Type { get; set; }

    public enum UserType {
        User,
        OtherUser
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this will work because I will have many different user types, each with many unique properties.

Comment: No. Just extending the AppUser class. I have also read about Claims based approaches, but I am not familiar with that approach.

Comment: Briefly explain your reason for having so many different user types?

Comment: Different users types will have access to separate views within the web application. And instead of dumping every user's properties into the AppUser class, the user types should be separated into different classes that contain only the properties for that user type.

Comment: I'd say you need to look at your structure and make sure it isn't too complex. We separate our users from permissions and groups which drive what they can, and cannot see.

Comment: Same as in the comments, I would use normal roles with the same user class type and an enum for the "user kind", then by role i could try to get the extra data depending on the roles. Using inheritance is really a bad idea, inheritance should be used when the Liskov Substitution Principle applies, if not, composition will be best.