# Different User Types in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Using Composition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

Today I explored creating different user types based on inheritance.

[How to Define and use Different User Types in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438247/how-to-define-and-use-different-user-types-in-asp-net-core)

After exploring solutions, I have learned that another approach is to use composition instead of inheritance.

The problem is that now when I run the initial migration, the following error is returned:

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Type1.User' and 'AppUser.Type1'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.

**Question**: How can users of different types be created using the following composition?

**AppUser.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Type1 Type1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Type1.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Type1
    {
        public int Type1Id { get; set; }
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may have to stick some annotations to say which is the FK

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: [ForeignKey("YourFkId")]

Comment: `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure which property I should apply this to though.

Comment: Please refer to article : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to [EF core relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?view=aspnetcore-2.1#other-relationship-patterns) to set one to one relationship.

Change `Type1.cs` to below code, then add migrations.

```
public class Type1
{
    public int Type1Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string AppUserId {get;set;}//As foreign Key
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

Create user with specific Type in `Register.cshtml.cs`.

```
var user = new AppUser {
                     UserName = Input.Email, 
                     Email = Input.Email,
                     Type1= new Type1{ Property1="Admin"} 
           };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```